# Setting results of torch.gather(...) calls

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch, tensor

I have a 2D pytorch tensor of shape n by m. I want to index the second dimension using a list of indices (which could be done with torch.gather) then **then also set new values** to the result of the indexing.

Example:

```py
data = torch.tensor([[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8]]) # shape (3,3)
indices = torch.tensor([1,2,1], dtype=torch.long).unsqueeze(-1) # shape (3,1)
# data tensor:
# tensor([[0, 1, 2],
#         [3, 4, 5],
#         [6, 7, 8]])
```

I want to select the specified indices per row (which would be `[1,5,7]` but then also set these values to another number - e.g. 42

I can select the desired columns row wise by doing:

```
data.gather(1, indices)
tensor([[1],
        [5],
        [7]])
data.gather(1, indices)[:] = 42 # **This does NOT work**, since the result of gather 
                                # does not use the same storage as the original tensor
```

which is fine, but I would like to change these values now, and have the change also affect the `data` tensor.

I can do what I want to achieve using this, but it seems to be very un-pythonic:

```py
max_index = torch.max(indices)
for i in range(0, max_index + 1):
  mask = (indices == i).nonzero(as_tuple=True)[0]
  data[mask, i] = 42
print(data)
# tensor([[ 0, 42,  2],
#         [ 3,  4, 42],
#         [ 6, 42,  8]])
```

Any hints on how to do that more elegantly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`torch.scatter_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.scatter.html) with the `value` option.

> `Tensor.scatter_(dim, index, src, reduce=None) → Tensor`
> Writes all values from the tensor `src` into `self` at the indices specified in the `index` tensor. For each value in `src`, its output `index` is specified by
> its index in src for `dimension != dim` and by the corresponding value
> in index for `dimension = dim`.
>
> With 2D tensors as input and `dim=1`, the operation is:
>
> `self[i][index[i][j]] = src[i][j]`

<sub>*No mention of the value parameter though...*</sub>

---

With `value=42`, and `dim=1`, this will have the following effect on data:

```
data[i][index[i][j]] = 42
```

Here applied in-place:

```
>>> data.scatter_(index=indices, dim=1, value=42)
>>> data
tensor([[ 0, 42,  2],
        [ 3,  4, 42],
        [ 6, 42,  8]])
```