# pytorch assigning to results of gather

Tags: pytorch

Suppose I have the following matrix, and its top 3 results across each row:

```py
p = torch.randn(5, 7)
val, idx = p.topk(3, dim=-1)
```

I wish to assign `x` to the top 3 results of each row where `x` is:

```py
x = torch.randn(5, 3)
```

Now I know that doing `torch.gather(p, -1, idx)` will get me the correct elements that I want to replace, but I cannot replace against the function `gather`. What is the best way of getting the effect of:

```py
torch.gather(p, -1, idx) = x
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I totally understand the question, but I know a potentially related piece of code from KPConv may help ( https://github.com/HuguesTHOMAS/KPConv-PyTorch/blob/master/models/blocks.py ). At the top of the file is three non-built-in implementations of `gather`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69100302/setting-results-of-torch-gather-calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use list-style indexing to p:

```
# create dummy indices to index the correct row (we need one value per value in idx)
row_idx = torch.arange(len(p)).unsqueeze(1).repeat(1,3)

# use flattened views
p[row_idx.view(-1),idx.view(-1)] = x.view(-1)
```

List-based indexing does require contiguous memory tensors, so you may pay a small computational penalty if p is non-contiguous, but I suspect any non-looping solution to this indexing task would have the same requirement.

Comment: Was there any reason why you didn't just do `p[row_idx, idx] = x` directly? It worked when I tried it atleast.

Comment: Yes that works as well but I think is slightly more confusing because you are using 2 multi-dimensional arrays to index a single dimension each of `p`. Both solutions first unravel the indexing arrays into a 1D vectors (as memory addresses are accessed serially) so the extra `view()` operations are just making explicit operations that  are implicitly performed anyway. The result is the same but I think the code is slightly more human-understandable in the unraveled case.